# can i send a flash sms from my android handset ? and q.2. how to send sms from mobile , without displaying sender's number?

Tags: android, sms

Can i send a flash sms from my android handset ? 
 q.2. how to send sms from mobile , without displaying sender's number ?

Various sites in the net allow you to do this , can this be done using some script / programming in  android ??
Thanks in advance 
Raj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a programming issue. The SMSC (SMS server) must allow this. Under normal conditions (i.e. when connected to the commercial SMSC's, not private dev&test SMSCs) this *is* allowed for MT messages (mobile terminated) (subject to account terms), but not for MO (mobile originated) messages.

Comment: How about the second part??
how do we send a sms without letting the receiver know the sender's original number/name ??

Comment: That's also the answer to part two: you sign a contract with the SMSC operator, and use their bulk interface. This interface allows you to set message options that you can't set for MO SMS.